# Failing JUnit tests for embedded Fongo DB

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit, fongo

I have a Spring Boot application which use MongoDB. I would like to use the embedded FongoDB for my JUnit tests. I follow some articles, for example:

http://dontpanic.42.nl/2015/02/in-memory-mongodb-for-unit-and.html

My Fongo test configuration looks like

```
package com.myproject.rest;

import com.github.fakemongo.Fongo;
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@Profile("test")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.myproject.service.data")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.myproject.service.data.repository")
@Configuration
public class MongoTestConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo-test";
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() {
        return new Fongo("mongo-test").getMongo();
    }

}
```

I have this dependency for that:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to test my services which autowired a repository interface which extends MongoRepository

```
package com.myproject.service.data.repository;

import com.myproject.service.data.entity.JournalData;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface JournalRepository extends MongoRepository<JournalData, String> {

    @Override
    public List<JournalData> findAll(Iterable<String> ids);
}
```

My tests class are inherited from the class below:

```
package com.myproject.rest;

import com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.mongodb.MongoDbRule;
import cz.csas.services.commons.api.RequestMetadata;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PowerMockIgnore;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.data.mongo.DataMongoTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic;
import static com.lordofthejars.nosqlunit.mongodb.MongoDbRule.MongoDbRuleBuilder.newMongoDbRule;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.*", "javax.management.*", "javax.net.ssl.*"})
@PrepareForTest({RequestMetadata.class})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EndpointTestContext {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;

    //@Rule
    //public MongoDbRule mongoDbRule = newMongoDbRule().defaultSpringMongoDb("demo-test");

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockStatic(RequestMetadata.class);
        when(RequestMetadata.builder()).thenCallRealMethod();
        RequestMetadata m = RequestMetadata.builder()
                .workingMode("TEST")
                .build();
        when(RequestMetadata.getMetadata()).thenReturn(m);
    }

}
```

But when I run the Maven tests I recieve the following:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions
    at com.mongodb.MockMongoClient.create(MockMongoClient.java:42)
    at com.github.fakemongo.Fongo.createMongo(Fongo.java:175)
    at com.github.fakemongo.Fongo.<init>(Fongo.java:88)
    at com.github.fakemongo.Fongo.<init>(Fongo.java:75)
    at com.github.fakemongo.Fongo.<init>(Fongo.java:67)
    at com.myproject.rest.MongoTestConfig.mongo(MongoTestConfig.java:30)
    at com.myproject.rest.MongoTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf18b1d4.CGLIB$mongo$1(<generated>)
    at com.myproject.rest.MongoTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf18b1d4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3ab8bfd7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358)
    at com.myproject.rest.MongoTestConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$bf18b1d4.mongo(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 115 common frames omitted
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fongo can't find class from `mongo-java-driver` artifact. It declares

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

as provided dependency. You should have `mongo-java-driver` on your test classpath. Most probably

```
<scope>runtime</scope>
```

or `test` will be enough for you.

Comment: Thank you Aleh, but it doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have **multiple version of mongo java driver** (version conflicts). To check this, you can use mvn dependency tree to trace the path from where each jar is coming to your project.

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Just need to find out the right version on mongo java driver and make sure you are not having version conflicts. I have used spring data and used fongo to write in-memory test case for mongodb queries.

```
<fongo-version>1.6.3</fongo-version>
<spring-data-mongodb-version>1.7.2.RELEASE</spring-data-mongodb-version>
<spring-framework-version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring-framework-version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-data-mongodb-version}</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
    <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
    <version>${fongo-version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
```

Version conflict can come from may source (can confirm using above mvc dependency:tree command, one such source is **mongobee**, so if you are using it, please **exclude** mongo-java-drive by using exclusion

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.mongobee</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongobee</artifactId>
    <version>${mongobee-version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>
```